# Baffled on windows password for installing mediamonkey as a service in win 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, login, services, mediamonkey

So I'm trying to install mediamonkey as a service.  That's just a button to click.  It then asks for my password for account "Steven".  Well, on windows, I don't actually have an account login "Steven" but rather "Steven [LASTNAME]", although under "users" my folder is "Steven" so I gather that's how they got that.

Backup:  I don't actually log onto my machine with a password, I use a pin.  My account is tied to my MS Live account and if I ever forget my pin, I use that to gain access.  That is the password I'm trying, but I keep getting a failure due to authentication error.

So what password is it looking for?  Is it that it is assuming my login name is "Steven" when it isn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a local administrator account and don't link it with anything.

Use commandline and enter the following:

> net user administrator password
>
> net user administrator /active:yes

Then log into that account using the password "password"

Install the program on that account after you're done enter the second line into the command line and change it from /active:yes to /active:no

Comment: While it didn't resolve my problem (I still have a logon failure message in MediaMonkey) I think your answer was excellent.  Only thing is perhaps to say "Use elevated commandline and enter the following"

Comment: Thanks for the advice! What does the failure message say? Does it still ask for the password for "Steven"?

Comment: "the service did not start due to a login failure".  And no, it isn't asking for "Steven" it is asking for "administrator".

Comment: It sounds like there's nothing wrong with the computer then adn this is a job for the Media Monkey support team